# Разделить слова пробелом Python

Tags: python

Допустим у меня есть текстовый файл и в нем находятся такие данные:

```
Example1 - Example1for
Example2 - Example2for
```

При выводе я должен получить:

```
Example1 - Example1 for
Example2 - Example2 for
```

Как реализовать пробел до слова 'for'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант:

```
lines = [
    'Example1 - Example1for',
    'Example2 - Example2for'
]

print(* [ line.replace('for', ' for') for line in lines ], sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

lines = [
    'Example1 - Example1for',
    'Example2 - Example2for'
]
if __name__ == '__main__':

    for line in lines:
        print(re.sub(r'^(.+)(for)$', r'\1 \2', line))

# Example1 - Example1 for
# Example2 - Example2 for
```